# Is 'Shortest Route/Distance' analysis is possible in GeoServer using OpenLayers 2.8...?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have configured a web based GIS Map using GeoServer and OpenLayers controls. Now I want to add 'Shortest Route' analysis in the same...

Any solution?

Comment: read about  postgis and pgrouting, that is one option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geoserver serves maps while OpenLayers displays them. None of those two can do routing maps as of this writing. What you need is something to do the shortest path computation.

I think it would be best to study PostGIS and pgrouting as @simplexio has suggested. PostGIS is a spatial database while pgrouting extends PostGIS by adding geospatial routing capabilities. Here's a [workshop that combines PostGIS, OpenLayers and pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/docs/ol-workshop/). It should be enough to get you started. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite open ended, but I assume what you are after would be some sort of routing engine.

GeoServer and OpenLayers do not have routing capabilities built in (someone can correct me if I am wrong though), so you would need some sort of routing engine on your server such as [RouteWare](http://www.routeware.dk/rwnetserver/rwnetserver.php), or you could use a web routing service such as the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

I hope this helps get you started.